# I want to pipe these two ffmpeg commands for to convert a video to grayscale frames

Tags: ffmpeg

Please, I want to pipe these two commands.
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf fps=1 out%d.png | ffmpeg -i input -vf format=gray output

Comment: They appear to be 2 independent FFmpeg calls (nothing is piped from the first to the second), please clarify

Comment: Dear Kesh, sure what I want is to pipe these 2 independet FFmpeg calls and I don't know how to do this. For this reason I'm askign for help. The first call is for to convert a color video to grayscale video, the other call is for to convert the grayscale video to frames.

Comment: Do you need to keep the grayscale video?

Comment: No my friend, just I need the frames.

Comment: Mi bad, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need frames, try this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -r 1 -pix_fmt gray out%d.png
```

There is no need to call it twice

- `-r` sets the output frame rate (1 frame/sec) dropping excess frames
- `pix_fmt` sets the output pixel format

[edit]

Try this to output both grayscale video and images:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv \
  -filter_complex format=gray,split[v0][v1]
  -map [v0] -r 1 out%d.png
  -map [v1] output.mp4
```

Comment: Dear Kesh, thanks for your help but seems that it doesn't work. 
I get the following error: At least one output file must be specified.

Comment: My bad, left out the pix_fmt option value. See the change.

Comment: Works good, but don't convert the video to grayscale frames. I would want to obtain a grayscale frames. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you do want grayscale video? (you said no earlier)

Comment: My bad, yes I want to convert the video to grayscale frames.

Comment: Thanks Kesh!! The command convert succesfully!!